# Weird language codes in Android locale

Tags: java, android, locale

My analytics package reports language and country of user devices. They come from `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` and `.getCountry()`, respectively.

The vast majority of language codes are sensible. But here are some locales that don't correspond to any known languages:

- md_US (MD is country code for Moldova (AKA Moldavia), but the language code used to be MO and is not used anymore)
- hd_US
- ld_US

Those are always paired with the US country code. I've got about 11 total.

I've checked in the [ISO table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), checked in the [Java docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html).

What could those be?

Comment: Maybe these values are coming from devices with custom ROM?

Comment: Maybe, but what kind of a locale is this?

Comment: I suggest these are invalid locales by custom rom makers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this could not be absolute answer, but its a little bigger than a comment,
if you don't like it i will delete it :)

**mostly it involves using custom a ROM as mentioned before**

i have found 2 things,

1- regarding ld_US MOSTLY it's running the app on emulator
not on real device, so i think some ppl are running your app on an emulator (i don't know why)

googled it, check the results, all logs have loc ld_US 
and at the top of the log or by the user declared using emulator

"I just try to test on emulator."
[here](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android/issues/7)

"[INFO] Launching Android emulator...one moment"
[here](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149050/trying-out-the-android)

2- regarding hd_US, i have found some post on xda-developers,talking about custom ROM
and it has a screenshot for language selected (HD United States) i don't know what is it
[here is the post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=52795221&postcount=1838) 
and here is the image

[image]

sorry if not useful, just tell me, i will delete it

**EDIT:**
the ROM with HD is cyanogenmod, so its common, [here is another post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=18284435)
talking about Market not working if language selected is HD (us)

Comment: Better than nothing :) So it's garbage. As for the emulator runs, it's a paid app. I presume those are the ones endeavoring to overcome said fact.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev well said :)